# electron : dialog box with window.prompt

Tags: node.js, electron

In [electron quick start demo](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start), I added this in index.html :

```
<script>
  query = window.prompt("What are you looking for?", "");
</script>
```

But it doesn't work when doing `npm start`. Why doesn't `window.prompt` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron doesn't provide an implementation for `window.prompt()`, you can read more about it in [issue #472](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/472).